# Antd expand icon table only when the same has a children

Tags: icons, antd

I saw an question here over the expand icon of a table on antd, but, following the function, the icon appear on every table, even the same hasn't childrens, someone know how to filter that to this icon appears only when the table column receive a children? that's the code:

```
customExpandIcon(props) {
if (props.expanded) {
    return <a style={{ color: 'black' }} onClick={e => {
        props.onExpand(props.record, e);
    }}><Icon type="minus" /></a>
} else {
    return <a style={{ color: 'black' }} onClick={e => {
        props.onExpand(props.record, e);
    }}><Icon type="plus" /></a>
}}


<Table
expandIcon={(props) => this.customExpandIcon(props)}
... />
```

Comment: What does it means "the icon appears on every table, even the same hasn't childrens", you should show it in your question, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can create an example in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the props parameter passed into the custom icon function, however I would need to know your data structure to give more specific guidance. Basically you can check if `props.record.myArrayofChildren` exists, and use it as a switch to return your icon or an empty tag. Something like:

```
customExpandIcon(props) {
if (props.record.myChildArray.length < 1) {
  return <span></span> //Empty tag, as I think Typescript requires you to return a JSX node
}
if (props.expanded) {
    return <a style={{ color: 'black' }} onClick={e => {
        props.onExpand(props.record, e);
    }}><Icon type="minus" /></a>
} else {
    return <a style={{ color: 'black' }} onClick={e => {
        props.onExpand(props.record, e);
    }}><Icon type="plus" /></a>
}

}
```